# How can I continuously observe the current position of dynamic UIView which is moving with a linear velocity?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView inside another UIView which I am moving using the UIDynamicAnimator. The gist of my implementation is as follows:

```
// Initialization
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
UIDynamicAnimator *dynamicAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];
UIDynamicItemBehavior *dynamicBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[subView]];
[dynamicBehavior setResistance:1.0];

// Move with some velocity in the y-axis
[dynamicBehavior addLinearVelocity:CGPointMake(0, 10) subView];
[dynamicAnimator addBehavior:dynamicBehavior];
```

I want to react as soon as the subView reaches a position on the screen. Is there a good way to do it? I tried using KVO pattern and added an observer to the subView's "frame" property but the observer doesn't seem to fire. Any alternatives?

Comment: can you post your KVO code?

Comment: Yes, I added the following line in the initialization block `[subView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];`
And added the observeValueForKeyPath method in self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing, I found out that adding observer for "center" property works great with the KVO pattern. The documentation mentions that UIDynamicAnimator uses the "center" property to animate which is why observing that directly, works great. Here is a working solution using UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
// Initialization - this should go in a method like init or viewDidLoad, etc
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
UIDynamicAnimator *dynamicAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];
UIDynamicItemBehavior *dynamicBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[subView]];
[dynamicBehavior setResistance:1.0];
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(subViewPanned:)];

// Add observer
[subView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Then where you want to start the animation (I do it in the handler for UIPanGestureRecognizer):

```
- (void) subViewPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    [dynamicAnimator removeAllBehaviors];
    // Add x component too if you want to capture that, my view just slides up and down
    CGFloat velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self].y;
    [dynamicBehavior addLinearVelocity:CGPointMake(0, velocity) forItem:subView];
    [dynamicAnimator addBehavior:dynamicBehavior];
}
```

Finally, here is where you would monitor the position of the subView as its being moved by the animator:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    // Do what you have to do here with the new position
}
```